# block .php .html extension

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am using a Godaddy domain and i want to block/get rid the extension of my files for example: `www.example.com/index.php` to `www.example.com/index`

I am aware of .htaccess so here is my RewriteRule code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 # Add trailing slash to url
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

# Remove .html-extension from url
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.html 

</IfModule>
```

someone help me please.

Comment: what issue are you facing?

Comment: i think you are using godaddy windows hosting?

Comment: @AyushGupta there's no issue but it doesn't work no error

Comment: @phpdroid yes sir

Answer (score 1):

## On Apache

Because you're on GoDaddy, you need to enable MultiViews in your .htaccess file.

Add the following code:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Should work. Reference: https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

## On IIS/Windows

IIS uses a web.config file instead of a .htaccess file. Create a file web.config in the root directory (or which every directory you want the rules to apply), and put the following code in it

```
<rewrite>
  <rule name="hide .php extension" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
  </rule>
</rewrite>
```

Reference: https://www.saotn.org/iis-url-rewrite-hide-php-extension/

Comment: This doesn't work also sir :( . Do i need to reconfigure all the href links?

Comment: What hosting are you on @PaulKevin? Apache, IIS or something else?

Comment: Plesk ?? im not that sure . hahaha but im using godaddy

Comment: @PaulKevin I've added an answer for IIS too. Try that out if you're unsure what you're running. Don't forget to restart the web server after putting the file on for the changes to take place

Comment: it says 
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.